# Java 7+ NIO - Globbing the entire filesystem

Tags: java, shell, nio, glob

In *nix systems, if you use a command with a glob on a directory, the shell (or the command?) doesn't check all the files in the filesystem.

For example:

```
ls /System/Library/J*/**

/System/Library/Java/Extensions:
MRJToolkit.jar

/System/Library/Java/Support:
CoreDeploy.bundle
```

My Mac hasn't checked the entire filesystem, just the files in /System/Library.
In Java 7+ NIO, to use globbing I've to create a `PathMatcher` and test some `Path`s on it. I'm building a command line application and the user should be able to insert a globbing pattern to select some files.
To match all the files on the directory / (recursively), I don't want to use a `DirectoryStream` on / because it's too slow. Obviously I could parse the pattern and split it into two parts, one without globs and one with globs, and match all the files in the first part on the second part. I'm wondering if there's a simple way to do that.

Another problem is that if the user inserts a path directly, the app shouldn't do any path matching. I'm looking for a method that takes in a `String` and gives me a `List<Path>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globbing is typically the shell's job, not each application's. In the example you gave, it's the shell that expands `/System/Library/J*/**` into a list of paths. `ls` does not see the glob. It sees the resulting list.

If that's the model you want to follow then the answer is: don't do anything. Just have your program expect a list of paths and let the shell take care of the rest.